# Can you attach an old Vixen model to a celestron tripod?

Tags: telescope, amateur-observing

I would like to know if I can put an old Vixen VMC model (15 years old) onto a celestron 4se tripod. I am aware that some adaptations must be made, but I want to know if it's even possible or if it will miss alignments by far, or not work at all.

Comment: Welcome to astronomy SE! I made some adjustments to your question so that it fits better to this site. I guess it would not hurt, if you add more details (which modifications you are talking about) or even pictures of the telescope mounting or the tripod head.